# Php Myadmin comparing two databases and updating one of them accordingly

Tags: php, .net

we have a virtual airline web site (We use MS Flight Simulator X) and we assign assignment flights to our virtual pilots every month. At the moment when they complete their assignment flight we have to mark this flight manually as "completed", can we do it automatically? Here are two tables:

the first one is : "assignments"

```
pid | flightno | departure | destination | aircraftcode | completed
3716| DAL11    | KBOS      | KJFK        | B738         |  1
3717| DAL12    | KLAX      | KMIA        | B777         |   0
```

(filled as example)
 On the database above we see that the first virtual pilot (Pilot ID is 3716) has completed his assignment flight (from Boston to NewYork with his Boeing 738) while the second pilot has not yet. (from Los Angeles to Miami..)

We, as the management of the virtual airline keep track of our pilots and if we see that they completed their flight, then we make the changes manually on the above mentioned database (delete 0 and make it 1)

Here is the second table: "flights"

```
pid - flightno - departure - destination - aircraftcode - flighttype - passengers - timeofflight - etc - etc
```

So, here is the question again : Can the first database update itself after checking the second database? Of course, if the pids match, if the flighttype on the second database is "assignment", if the departures and destinations match each other. Is it possible ?

Comment: I think the correct term would be *tables* **not** *databases*.

Comment: You can do it directly in MySQL by using triggers.

Comment: I have tried the following code only to receive some errors. What wrong am I doing here??                               create trigger assgnmnt_cmplted
AFTER INSERT on flights

DECLARE @flgpid VARCHAR
DECLARE @flgno VARCHAR
DECLARE @flgdept VARCHAR
DECLARE @flgdest VARCHAR

select @flgpid=pid,@flgno=flightno,@flgdept=departure,@flgdest=destination from inserted

UPDATE assignments SET completed=1
      WHERE pid=@flgpid and @flgno=flightno and @flgdept=departure and @flgdest=destination
      
SELECT * FROM `assignments` WHERE 1